# Algorithm that results in Scale2x-like result but is robust with floating-point values

Tags: algorithm, image-processing

Scale2x is a simple algorithm that can fill diagonals so they appear "thick" after upscaling.

[image: Circle scale2x]

This algorithm requires checking for equality:

```cpp
auto const a01 = src(l, k - 1).value();
auto const a10 = src(l - 1, k).value();
auto const a11 = src(l, k).value();
auto const a12= src(l + 1, k).value();
auto const a21 = src(l, k + 1).value();

ret(2*l, 2*k).value() = a10 == a01 && a01 != a21 && a10 != a12 ? a10 : a11;
ret(2*l + 1, 2*k).value() = a01 == a12 && a01 != a21 && a10 != a12 ? a12 : a11;
ret(2*l, 2*k + 1).value() = a10 == a21 && a01 != a21 && a10 != a12 ? a10 : a11;
ret(2*l + 1, 2*k + 1).value() = a21 == a12 && a01 != a21 && a10 != a12 ? a12 : a11;
```

Which may not be a robust operation if the values are floats. Besides quantization to an integer by scaling values by a factor 2^k, and then rounding, or introducing tolerances, is there a way to achieve similar output in a more robust way. That is, an algorithm that works without equality.

Answer (score 0):

I think you touched on the only workable answer in your question: use a tolerance.  It's not hard to do if you turn it into a function.

```
bool eq(double d1, double d2)
{
    const double tolerance = 8.0;
    return abs(d1-d2) <= tolerance;
}

ret(2*l, 2*k).value() = eq(a10, a01) && !eq(a01, a21) && !eq(a10, a12) ? a10 : a11;
```

Choose the tolerance based on values that are barely distinguishable from each other.  I chose 8 for the common scale of 0-255.